# Regex to not match more than one trailing slash in string

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-negation

Looking for a regex to not match more than 1 occurrence of a trailing slash

```
api/v1
/api/v1
/api/2v1/21/
/api/blah/v1/
/api/ether/v1//
/api/23v1///
```

Expected match

```
/api/v1
/api/2v1/21/
/api/blah/v1/
```

What I tried:

```
^\/([^?&#\s]*)(^[\/{2,}\s])$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the pattern that you tried, the second part of the pattern can not match, it asserts the start of the string `^` and then matches a *single* character in the character class `(^[\/{2,}\s])$` directly followed by asserting the end of the string.

```
^\/([^?&#\s]*)(^[\/{2,}\s])$

              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But you have already asserted the start of the string here `^\/`

You can repeat a pattern starting with `/` followed by repeating 1+ times the character class that you already have:

```
^(?:\/[^\/?&#\s]+)+\/?$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:\/[^\/?&#\s]+)+` Repeat 1+ times `/` and 1+ char other than the listed ones
- `\/?` Optional `/`
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wvNxPX/1)

Answer (score 3):

By use of a negative [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?!.*//)/.*
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/leSXPs/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
^(?:/[^/?&#\s]+)*/?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bx1a7c/2).

*Details*

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:/[^/?&#\s]+)*` - zero or more repetitions of a `/` char followed with one or more chars other than `/`, `?`, `&`, `#` and whitespace
- `/?` - an optional `/`
- `$` - end of string.